# Caret width too small on 288 DPI

Tags: high-dpi

I use 288 DPI meaning 300 % zoom and have a caret width of only 1 pixel in all apps based on win32 and wpf, most apps are either win32 or wpf so it is a severe issue for me.

I reported this to the Visual Studio support, and they say they cannot reproduce it and proved it with a screenshot.

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/623984/carat-width-system-setting-is-not-compatible-with.html?childToView=629401#comment-629401

Am I really the only person with this severe issue?

Comment: "Am I really the only person with this severe issue?". Surely not.